# Clickable chart data points to open new pages

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I would like to be able to click on the bars and directly open a new page associated with that bar.

I have researched and was able to make the x-axis clickable, but I need the bars or circle clickable instead.

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
      ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
    ],
    type: 'bar'
  },
  axis: {
    rotated: true
  }
});

var arrayOfLinks = [
  "http://google.com",
  "http://google.com",
  "http://google.com",
  "http://google.com",
  "http://google.com",
  "http://google.com",
];

d3.selectAll('.c3-axis-x .tick tspan')
  .each(function(d, i) {
    // augment tick contents with link
    var self = d3.select(this);
    var text = self.text();
    self.html("<A xlink:href='" + arrayOfLinks[i] + "'>" + text + "</A>");
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.11/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.11/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

I am almost certain that the fix lies in this line of code:

```
d3.selectAll('.c3-axis-x .tick tspan')
```

What should the argument be? `'data.coloums[1]','bar'` ?

Please shed some light.

Comment: can you add a reproducible snippet here ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I will going forward.

Comment: try with `.c3-bar` selector. and inspect the elements they are most likely to be some `path` or `rect` elements. also, check for `rect` selection [here](https://www.d3indepth.com/selections/)

Comment: Tried '.c3-bar', '.c3-rect'.... I am hoping someone knows the exact keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out [here](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/262) in the issue, for bar charts you can specify an `onclick` function, when you pass in the data. This function can trigger an even to `window.open` the link.

A snippet of the code is here:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
      ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
    ],
    type: 'bar',
    //define the onclick function
    onclick: function (d) { 
      console.log(d) //checks the data
      //note that the index for the values gets passed as d.x
      window.open(arrayOfLinks[d.x]); 
    },
  },
  axis: {
    rotated: true
  },

});
```

A full working block for the code is here:

http://bl.ocks.org/akulmehta/87f4903a4686deb8285381b8e816ce4d